# Navigate without using sub ids

Tags: php

i am just setting up the general template for my website and the little bit of php that i am doing is to just get the users id from page to page, in other words i want the user while logged in to go from page to page, without using the sub id in the header of user_id=3 for example, and then using the get function to get it and display their information, i want to be able to do it without that.

Here is my code but i keep getting the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arken\profile.php on line 7
```

LOGIN CODE (not all of it of course, just the bit for setting the sessions tuff)

```
// Create session var for their raw id
                $user_id = $row["user_id"];   
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // Create the idx session var
                $_SESSION['idx'] = base64_encode("g4p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234$id");
                // Create session var for their username
                $login_username = $row["login_username"];
                $_SESSION['login_username'] = $login_username;
                // Create session var for their password
                $login_userpass = $row["login_password"];
                $_SESSION['login_userpass'] = $login_userpass;
```

PHP for each page

```
    session_start();

$user_id = "";


if ($_GET['user_id']) {

     $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

} else if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

     $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

} else {

   include_once "index.php";
   exit();
}
include 'connect_to_mysql.php';
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming line 7 is

```
if ($_GET['user_id']) {
```

Try making sure it's set before using it:

```
if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it did exactly what i needed, i am just curious though, is it better to use sub ids like i had it before or better to do it with how you just suggested, because i have had a look at a couple if big websites such as facebook etc... and noticed they use subids for the user id as well, is it better that way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the warning level `E_NOTICE` and this line:

```
if ($_GET['user_id'])
```

If the value for `user_id` is not set, this creates an error. If you only want to check whether or not the value is present, you should therefore use:

```
if (isset($_GET['user_id']))
```